# Display Group Price to all users

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, theme, group-price

I'm having trouble displaying the group price to all users, i'm running 1.9

it obviously works if you're logged in and a user, but i need to display it to non members to entice them to become a member.

Comment: Do you mean to say if your product has a group price you want to display it to all users even if they are guest users?

Answer (score 3):

You can load the group prices using the **backend model**  of the `group_price` attribute. The following code loads and outputs all group prices:

```
$groupPrices = $ProductObject->getData('group_price');
if (is_null($groupPrices)) {
    $attribute = $ProductObject->getResource()->getAttribute('group_price');
    if ($attribute){
        $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($ProductObject);
        $groupPrices = $ProductObject->getData('group_price');
    }
}

if (!is_null($groupPrices) || is_array($groupPrices)) {
    foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {

        $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($groupPrice['website_price'], true, false);

        echo "Customer group: ", $groupPrice['cust_group'];
        echo "Group price: ", $formattedPrice;
    }

}
```

Comment: where to add this code inside **template/catalog/product/view.phtml** ?

Comment: you use this code at any where   you have product object

Comment: I am new to magento and I need to show all group prices on the product page. can you tell me the specific file in which I can put this and group prices will show on the product page

Answer (score -1):

1. You need create different customer groups. **In Backend -> Customer -> Customer Groups**
2. Go to the product page, and select product you want to show different price for customers. In **Catalog -> Manage products**, choose one product and select left side tab '**prices**'. In right side you will see there has a **group price** field, then you can click '**add group price**' for different customer group for different price.

*friendly remind:  show some information about there is different price if become a member on the home page